# Bluetooth 2.1 file transfer speed on Windows 10

Tags: windows, windows-10, performance, bluetooth, speed

I'm testing Bluetooth file transmission between Windows 10 hosts. After several tests I measured around 30 KB/s. I have also created a Winsock test application, and I achieve between 40 and 50 KB/s. Are these numbers expected/normal? Shouldn't I get about 200 KB/s?

Comment: There are more than one Bluetooth specifications, Can you specify what type of bluetooth devices are you trying?

Comment: The devices are Bluetooth 2.1

Comment: The specification says you can get a max data rate of 2.1 Mbps, which is 262.5 KB/s. Just putting it out there, but "some products may claim compliance to "Bluetooth v2.0" without supporting the higher data rate. At least one commercial device states "Bluetooth v2.0 without EDR" on its data sheet."(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#Bluetooth_2.1_.2B_EDR). Even if your device isn't EDR, the max data rate would be 1Mbit/s, or 125KB/s. So I'd then take a look at https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201542 And maybe invest in a Bluetooth 3.0 or 4.0 device if it's the transmitter/receiver itself

Comment: @cody.codes May be you should add that as an answer

Comment: @cody.codes Yes please add it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The specification says you can get a max data rate of 2.1 Mbps, which is 262.5 KB/s.

According to a citation on Wikipedia (can't open the citation now due to a server error on Wayback Machine), "[some products may claim compliance to "Bluetooth v2.0" without supporting the higher data rate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bluetooth#cite_note-47)"

Even if your device isn't EDR, the max data rate would be 1Mbit/s, or 125KB/s.

I'd then take a look at [Potential sources of Wi-Fi and Bluetooth interference](http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201542) And maybe invest in a Bluetooth 3.0 or 4.0 device if it's the transmitter/receiver itself